# how to log runtime errors in grails

Tags: grails, log4j

I am trying to debug a simple problem with saving my domain object.

```
class AppRideOfferController {
    def index() {}
    def create() {
        if(params.fromAddr && params.toAddr && params.preferences && params.startDate) {
            RideOffer rideOffer = new RideOffer(startLocation: params.fromAddr, endLocation: params.toAddr, startDateTime: new Date(Integer.parseInt((String) params.startDate)));
            rideOffer.save(flush: true);
            //assert(rideOffer.id);
            log.info("blah");
            render(contentType:"text/json") {
                result(blah: rideOffer)
            };
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, I am simply creating a domain object, saving it, and returning it as json with the generated id in it. However, if I uncomment the asset statement, it fails because id is not set.

I do not get any error on the console, so I wonder how do I get runtime error stacktraces onto the stdout? My Config.groovy's log4j configuration looks like this:

```
log4j = {
    // Example of changing the log pattern for the default console appender:
    //
    appenders {
        console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
    }
    info 'grails.app.controllers',
         'grails.app.controller',
         'grails.app';
    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
}
```

Comment: How does the domain class look like? Are you specifically mentioning the generator to be `assigned` in the mappings?

Answer (score 1):

If your code generates a runtime error, you will see the `error.gsp` view. In the documentation you can see that the `save()` will not produce an exception, but populate `errors` that can happen in the validation of your domain class. If you [generate your controller](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/generate-controller.html) you will see how you can handle errors in the save method.

Something like:

```
def save() {

  if(!instance.save(flush:true)) {
    //instance fails in validation, you need to respond those errors
    Locale locale = RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request) //Locale of the user
    render([success: false, errors: errorsToMap(instance.errors, locale)]) as JSON
  } else {
    render([success: true, record: instance]) as JSON
  }
}

//just a helper to format the errors output
private List<Map> errorsToMap(Errors errors, Locale locale) {

  def error = []

  for(def err : errors.allErrors) {
    if(err instanceof FieldError) {
      error << [id: err.field, msg: Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getMessage(err, locale)]
    }
  }

  return error
}
```

`Holders`, `JSON` and `RequestContextUtils` are available by default.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing  rideOffer.save(flush: true); with  rideOffer.save(flush: true, failOnError:true); and you should see errors in console

Comment: Don't use `failOnError:true` when processing user-supplied params - using exceptions for non-exception cases like this (you should always expect that users make mistakes or try to hack your site) is wrong, and rather expensive.